# Trying to override CSS wordpress default bold color of white

Tags: css, wordpress

Looking to override css wordpress default bold color of white. I do not want to override the default color of white everywhere, just when i need to.  I what to do this with css. I can use a custom class to for each title.

For titles like:

KOREKOTE APPLICATIONS or KOREKOTE FEATURES.

http://www.korekote.com/epoxy-coating/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**HTML:**

```
<strong class="black_text">KOREKOTE</strong>
```

**CSS:**

```
#theme-page strong.black_text {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Use the text color as per your requirement. I used black text color. Hope this helps you!